# How do I ensure attribute values containing quotes do not break formatting?

Tags: php, html, encoding

In my database I am storing the title of posts and when I create the links on the page I put the title of the post as the title attribute.

```
<a title='here is the description'>bluah</a>
```

But what is happening on the page is that in my descriptions there are characters that are breaking it. Example of a post title that breaks

```
<a title='I don't hanging out with friends, had a great time seeing Sarah again ;p '>bluah</a>
```

I think I need to do some HTML encoding, but I am not sure when/where I should be doing that.

Thanks

Comment: which server side language are you using?

Comment: Continuing @lbu, you should escape this with regex and your server-side programming language. E.g "What\'s the time"

Comment: @Ibu sorry forgot to add that, php/mysql

Comment: @hrr should i be doing that before it goes into the database?

Comment: No. When you put something in the database, use the mysqli/pdo functions to make sure it's safe to go in. When you retrieve the data, you determine how you want to use it and what escapes are required. Depending on what you want, you could use `addslashes()` or `htmlentities()` or something else.

Comment: @arjan thanks. is there a place/resource you would recommend to read up on mysqli/pdo functions for safe data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `htmlspecialchars` to output your strings

```
htmlspecialchars("I don't",ENT_QUOTES); // returns I don&#039;t
```

That will also take care of other HTML characters such as < & > as explained in the manual,

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: about to go read about htmlentities and htmlspecialchars but since you two seem to know more about this then me.. is one better than the other?

Comment: well, always go with the guy with the highest reputation :) answer updated

Comment: @MickeySlater Well, `htmlspecialchars` does only replace HTML’s special characters while `htmlentities` replaces any character where there is an entity that represents it: `htmlspecialchars('<Äpfel>')==='&lt;Äpfel&gt;'` while `htmlentities('<Äpfel>')==='&lt;&Auml;pfel&gt;'`.

Comment: htmlspecialchars will replace only the characters that can break your HTML.. which is exactly what you need.